# Windows DirectShow: how to play multiple mp3s?

Tags: windows, mp3, directshow, latency

I have to play multiple sounds in my UI, like button clicks, errors, notifications etc. For this purpose, I've written the following code (never played mp3s in Windows before):

```
bool ClientHandler::InitSoundAndMusic()
{
    m_pSoundGraph = NULL;
    m_pSoundControl = NULL;

    HRESULT hr = ::CoCreateInstance(CLSID_FilterGraph, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IGraphBuilder,
                                    (void**) &m_pSoundGraph);

    if (!SUCCEEDED(hr) || !m_pSoundGraph)
        return false;

    hr = m_pSoundGraph->QueryInterface(IID_IMediaControl, (void**) &m_pSoundControl);
    if (!SUCCEEDED(hr) || !m_pSoundControl)
        return false;

    return true;
}

void ClientHandler::PlayFile(LPCTSTR file)
{
    if (!m_pSoundGraph)
        return;

    m_pSoundControl->Stop();
    HRESULT hr = m_pSoundGraph->RenderFile(file, NULL);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        m_pSoundControl->Run();
}

bool ClientHandler::OnEvent(const String& message)
{
    if (message == _T("button"))
    {
        PlayFile(_T(".\\sound\\button.mp3"));
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

It seems to be very slow. When I click a button ~5 times per second, the UI just freezes. I guess, I shouldn't call Stop/Render/Run every time, but I don't know how to avoid it. How should I rewrite the code?

Regards,

Comment: The problem here is here that you reuse the same member variables and either destroy previously created pipeline every time you create new one, or even - in a more messy way - mix them together. It is unclear whether you are releasing the interface pointers correctly.

Comment: I call Release() on app destroying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of DirectShow, I just tried libzplay (http://libzplay.sourceforge.net/).

Let me quote its readme:

> How to use libZPlay with C++
>
> 1. Include libzplay.h into your source code
> 2. Include libZPlay namespace
>
>    using namespace libZPlay;
> 3. Link your project with import library.
>
>    libzplay.lib          - VC++ import library for libzplay.dll
>      libzplay_borland.lib  - Borland C++ import library for libzplay.dll
>      libzplay.a            - MinGW/GCC import library for libzplay.dll
> 4. Create ZPlay class.
>
>    ZPlay *player = CreateZPlay();
> 5. Open file.
>
>    if(player->OpenFile("mySong.mp3", sfAutodetect) == 0)    {
>        // error    }
> 6. Start playing
>
>    player->Play();
> 7. At the end destroy ZPlay class
>
>    player->Release();

It works smoothly. I can open a file just once and call Play() every time I need. Calling Run() in DirectShow didn't work in the same way.

That's how The Right Library must be: 30 minutes to embed from scratch and solid rock.